# How to Remove the column heading while fetching the excel sheet data through the PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-module

While fetching the data from the excel through the PowerShell, along with that we are getting the column heading and datatype is "PSCustomObject".
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

so can any one help to remove the column heading as well as changing the datatype from `PSCustomObject` to `String`.

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter. See the linked duplicate for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).SomeProperty`

Comment: In other words: `Select Name` -> `Select -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Working fine, Thank you, i will make sure that above format will be doing from the next time.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and thanks for being willing to heed the formatting advice in the future.